# What does "an equation system is coupled"?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've read a lot the expresion "coupled equations" but I can´t get a precise definition of the term.

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-if-two-equations-are-coupled-or-uncoupled and https://www.google.com/#q=coupled+system+of+equations

Answer (score 4):

A system of differential equations is said to be coupled if knowledge of one variable depends upon knowing the value of another variable.

Here is an example:

\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt} & = 3x^3 + 2y\\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= xyz\\
\frac{dz}{dt} &= x + 2y + z^2
\end{cases}

I've actually explained these [here](http://dantaylor688.github.io/2015/11/03/decoupling-differential-equations/)